# Windows Batch File Math Weirdness

Tags: math, batch-file, for-loop

Why doesn't this work?

```
@echo off

for /l %%i in (0, 1, 100) do (
    for /l %%j in (0, 1, 10) do (
        set /a curr=%%i*10 + %%j
        echo %curr%
    )
    echo "-----------------------------"
)
```

This is the output I get from this:

```
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
"----------------------------"
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
1010
...
```

It seems like it precomputes the math before executing, so that when it does finally execute, `%curr%` is already at 1010.  How do I keep it from doing that?  I'm trying to get output like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
"----------------------------"
11
12
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer from Johannes Rössel (for those who might look for it later):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

for /l %%i in (0, 1, 100) do (
    for /l %%j in (0, 1, 10) do (
        set /a curr=%%i*10+%%j
        echo !curr!
    )
    echo "-----------------------------"
)
```

Comment: k, fixed that in my question (in my actual batch file I had the `/a` in there correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use delayed expansion by putting the following line before your loops:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
```

And then use the environment variable as `!curr!` instead of `%curr%`.

You're changing the contents of an environment variable within a block *and* use the changed content again in the same block. This can't work without delayed expansion. The reason is that `cmd` expands variables like `%foo%` while parsing a command – and a command like `if` or `for` includes the block that may follow as well. Delayed expansion causes variables to be evaluated right before executing a command which is what you want here.

`help set` includes a description of what goes wrong without delayed expansion and works with it.

Comment: Awesome!  Works great!  Thanks!  Here's the code with the changes for anyone else looking for it:

    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
    
    for /l %%i in (0, 1, 100) do (
        for /l %%j in (0, 1, 10) do (
            set /a curr=%%i*10+%%j
            echo !curr!
        )
        echo "-----------------------------"
    )